# Interpolating an XML string containing double quotes and colons in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string-interpolation

In Ruby, I am taking an incoming from a file representing an XML document, but containing some Ruby interpolation code. Here is an example:

```
<ns1: xmlns:ns1="http://example.com" attr="#{Time.now}">
```

Now, when I want to evaluate the string to resolve the Ruby references, I have tried the following:

```
xs = '<ns1: xmlns:ns1="http://example.com" attr="#{Time.now}">'
eval("'" + xs + "'") #=> "<ns1: xmlns:ns1=\"http://example.com\" attr=\"\#{Time.now}\">"
eval %Q{"'" + #{xs} + "'"} # SyntaxError: (eval):1: syntax error, unexpected '<'
eval('"' + %Q{#{xs}} + '"') # SyntaxError: (eval):1: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input
```

I don't know how else to do this. How can I evaluate the string with interpolation so that I get the following:

```
<ns1: xmlns:ns1="http://example.com" attr="2017-06-22 11:58:39 +0200">
```

Comment: If only you could change `#{ }` to `<%= %>` :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes, but then presumably I'd need to use ERB, and I just want to use the built-in interpolation capability, if possible.

Comment: Using ERB is not at all complicated. `ERB.new(xs).result(binding)`. That's it. Making interpolation work here is going to be more problematic (if possible at all)

Comment: I have decided on a solution involving gsub and replacing any instances of the Ruby interpolation syntax and evaluating the contents. (So it's not really interpolation, but it's using no additional libraries). Thanks anyway.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Why don't you submit the ERB suggestion as an answer? I think I might go for that now after having tried my own solution.

Comment: "but it's using no additional libraries" - ERB is built-in. It's not an additional library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by Jörg, you'll have much better experience if you use one of the templating languages. I suggested ERB, because it's built-in.

```
xs = '<ns1: xmlns:ns1="http://example.com" attr="<%= Time.now %>">'

require 'erb'
ERB.new(xs).result(binding) 
# => "<ns1: xmlns:ns1=\"http://example.com\" attr=\"2017-06-23 09:11:56 +0300\">"
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not looking for string interpolation. You are looking for a templating language.

String interpolation is for interpolating Ruby code in a string (or symbol) literal. You don't have a literal, you have a reference to an object. String interpolation doesn't work, it doesn't even apply to this situation.

What you have here instead is a templating language whose syntax happens to be identical to Ruby's string interpolation syntax. You need an implementation for that language; unfortunately, AFAIK there isn't one, so you will have to write your own. Writing a very simple, not very robust templating engine used to be a popular exercise in Ruby a couple of years ago, so I happen to know that it only takes a couple of minutes (and lines). (Making it robust, safe, and secure in the face of untrusted arbitrary input is a whole different matter, though.)

If you could change the input format to an existing templating language, that would be easiest. One well-known templating language in the Ruby world is ERb, which actually has an implementation in the standard library. There's also Tenjin, Liquid, Ruty, Mustache, to name but a few.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jörg. I was thinking that I am probably not using the term "interpolation" correctly. As you can see from my answer, I have done pretty much what you are saying, created another template solution. It's totally unsafe, but will probably do what I need for now.